# Prove that $ \sqrt{\sum\limits^n_{k=1}(x_k-y_k)^2} \leq \sqrt {\sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_k^2} + \sqrt{\sum\limits^n_{k=1}y_k^2} $

Tags: inequality

Because both sides are $\geq 0$, we square them, and we get
$$ \sum\limits^n_{k=1}(x_k-y_k)^2 \leq \sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_k^2 + \sum\limits^n_{k=1}y_k^2+2\sqrt{\sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_k^2\sum\limits^n_{k=1}y_k^2} $$
$$ \sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_k^2+\sum\limits^n_{k=1}y_k^2-2\sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_ky_k\leq \sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_k^2 + \sum\limits^n_{k=1}y_k^2+2\sqrt{\sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_k^2\sum\limits^n_{k=1}y_k^2} $$
$$ -2\sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_ky_k\leq 2\sqrt{\sum\limits^n_{k=1}x_k^2\sum\limits^n_{k=1}y_k^2}$$
I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give the answer in terms of the norm and you can work out how to transform it into whatever argument form you require. First note that 
$$\|u-v\|^2=(u-v)\cdot (u-v)=u\cdot u-2u\cdot v -v\cdot v=\|u\|^2-2u\cdot v+\|v\|^2$$
Then note that 
$$(\|u\|+\|v\|)^2=\|u\|^2+2\|u\|\|v\|+\|v\|^2$$
Finally it can be seen with the Cauchy Schwarz inequality (proof readily available with a quick Google search) that
$$-2u\cdot v=2(-u)\cdot v\leq 2\|-u\|\|v\|=2\|u\|\|v\|$$
So in conclusion
$$\|u-v\|^2\leq (\|u\|+\|v\|)^2$$
As $t^2$ is monotone increasing on the positive axis the proof follows.

Answer (score 1):

If we think geometrically, we are given $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and we want to show that 
$$\|x-y\|\leq \|x\| + \|y\|$$ 
which follows readily from the triangle inequality: we have 
$$ \|x\| + \|y\| = \|x\| + \|-y\| \geq \|x-y\|$$

Edit: as one of the comments quite rightly pointed out, it should have been obvious to me from the beginning you were asking about a proof of the triangle inequality, so sorry about that. In the above notation, you've reduced the question to proving that $-\langle x, y\rangle \leq \|x\|\|y\|$, equivalent to $\langle x,y\rangle \leq \|x\|\|y\|$ after say multiplying $x$ by $-1$. This is precisely the content of the [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality, which has been discussed on this forum, in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275989/proof-of-cauchy-schwarz-inequality) question.

Comment: I think the poster is asking how to prove the triangle inequality.